# MongoError: topology was destroyed(when finding the documents) and instance pool was destroyed (when inserting documents)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mean-stack

I'm trying to build REST API with Node.js, Express and Mongodb. I'm using mongodb npm package to connect to the database, below is my sever.js file code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var Server = mongo.Server;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var ObjectID = mongo.ObjectID;
try{    
    var config = require('./configure.js');
}catch(e){
    console.log("configuration file is hidden on github for security");
    config = null;
}
var usersCollection = config.usersCollection;
var login = require('./routes/login/index.js');
var signup = require('./routes/signup/index.js');
var Database = new Db(process.env.DBNAME || config.DBNAME , new Server(process.env.DBHOST || config.DBHOST, process.env.DBPORT || config.DBPORT, {'native_parser': true}));


Database.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
        if(err){
            console.log("Failed to connect to the database. Please Check the connection");
            throw err;
        }else{
            Database.authenticate(process.env.DBUSER || config.DBUSER, process.env.DBPASS || config.DBPASS, function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Authentication Failed"); 
                    throw err; 
                }else{
                    console.log("Connected to the database Successfully");
                    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
                    app.use(bodyParser.json());
                    var users = Database.collection(usersCollection);
                    login(app,users);
                    signup(app,users);

                    Database.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Server Started Listening to port : "+port);
});
```

routes/login/index.js

```
module.exports = function(app,users){
app.route('/login')
   .post(function(req,res){
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var query = {'FirstName':username};

        users.find().toArray(function(err,docs){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }else{
                console.log("no err");
                if(doc.LastName == password){
                    res.send({status : true});
                }else{
                    res.send({status : false});
                }
            }
        });
   });
```

}

and routes/signup/index.js

```
module.exports = function(app,users){
app.route('/signup')
   .post(function(req,res){
        var doc = { EmpNo:"1",
                    FirstName:"Andrew",
                    LastName:"Neil",
                    Age:"30",
                    Gender:"Male",
                    Skill:"MongoDB",
                    Phone:"408-1234567",
                    Email:"Andrew.Neil@gmail.com",
                    Salary:"80000"
        };

        users.insert(doc,function(err,info){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }else{
                console.log('Successfully inserted ' + JSON.stringify(info));
                res.send({result: 'done'});
            }
        });
    });
```

}

When i'm trying to insert documents in server.js , i'm able to insert them successfully but through routes/signup/index.js i'm getting instance pool was destroyed similarly if i try to find the documents in server.js no error but if i try to do it from routes/login/index.js then i'm getting error as topology was destroyed.

Need help to resolve it.

Answer (score 5):

Those errors are thrown if connection is somehow cut in the middle of the process.

Because both `users.find()` and `users.insert()` functions are async your server.js file reaches to the `Database.close()` function and closes the connection to your database before it finishes the process thus giving the errors.

Comment: I got the point, I removed Database.close() statement, it's working fine. Thank you.